# broken bind mount: files not present and "Please use `keyctl unlink`"

Tags: linux, mount, snap

I have a bind mount in fstab which makes certain files visible within the filesystem of a snap application (MuseScore)

```
/path/to/real/files /home/me/MuseScore3Development/Scores none defaults,bind,users 0 0
```

This was working for a while, i.e. `/path/to/real/files/foo.mscz` was visible in `/home/me/MuseScore3Development/Scores` to the application.

Now,

```
#> mount | grep Scores                                  
/dev/sda3 on /home/me/MuseScore3Development/Scores type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

seems to indicate that it is mounted, but

```
ls /home/me/MuseScore3Development/Scores
```

shows nothing whereas

```
ls /path/to/real/files
```

shows the expected files. But if I save a file from the application it appears in `/home/me/MuseScore3Development/Scores`

Also

```
#> sudo umount /home/me/MuseScore3Development/Scores`
Could not unlink the key(s) from your keying. Please use `keyctl unlink` if you wish to remove the key(s). Proceeding with umount.
umount: /home/me/MuseScore3Development/Scores: not mounted.

# mount | grep Scores
/dev/sda3 on /home/me/MuseScore3Development/Scores type ext4 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

1. Why does it say `not mounted` desppite clearly being still mounted?
2. Why do the files in the source directory not appear in the mount point?
3. What does `keyctl` have to do with any of this?
4. What sequence of events plausible caused this situation, and how do I avoid this problem in the future?

Comment: Have you tried to run `sudo keyctl clear @u` ? If the disk is encrypted see [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1138613/finding-ecrypt-recover-private-mountpoint). See also [this article](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/best-practices-security-new-ubuntu-server-apparmor-certs-ecryptfs-encrypted-lvm/).